# Doorways without molding: intentional design or molding removed?

Tags: trim, door-frame

All doorways in my home lack moulding. There appears to be quarter round that is flush with the walls, which I don't love. Is this a style? Or has the moulding been removed for painting and not replaced? Can I simply add moulding around the doorways without it looking strange?

[image: Bottom of doorways]

[image: Top of doorways]

Comment: They look finished.  It takes a lot of work to make doorways look like that.  Trim is used to hide not perfect edges, like drywall a 1/4 inch from the door frame.

Comment: And it will take a lot of work to get it to a typical detail, since it was designed for that type of finish. Jamb extensions would need to be added on both sides, before adding an trim that will set over the drywall surface.

Comment: Work like that for the doorways, will probably mean the rest of the house is also up to top notch work.  The builder did not scrimp on quality work.

Comment: This is why design/style questions are off-topic. I love the look of that! Of course, you're not asking for an opinion on the style, you've stated you don't like it. As noted, this is very definitely intentional and took a _lot_ of effort to create. It's possible that it will boost resale value in the future, so you may want to think about that before undoing it if you're not planning on being here too long...

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Forgive my naive questions. I'll interpret your comments to mean that this style cannot hide imperfections, and unfortunately there are many spots where the quarter round lip is visible or there are rough spots of (I'm guessing) drywall mud. Perhaps I can fix that with spackle/mud and a paint job?

Comment: I highly recommend editing your question to reflect your dislike of the bullnose imperfections and ask for suggestions to address them. As it stands, you're soliciting approval of a solution which very few agree with.

Comment: I think my question has been answered. I'll post a separate question about fixing the imperfections if I want more help. I'll need better pictures to show the imperfections anyway, it sounds like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly it is **a** style.  Whether or not it's *stylish* is up to you to decide (you seem to think it is not).  It was clearly done on purpose, and it seems to have been well executed (outside of its aesthetics).

Regardless, I imagine you're stuck with it, it seems to me it would be extremely hard to change to regular trim.

Answer (score 1):

To trim the doors you would have to mill out the back-side of a larger piece of trim to accommodate the bullnose corner. This is **A LOT** of work.

Good luck getting anyone to do it for a reasonable price.

[image]

---

If the floor trim is bugging you then one solution could be to cut the existing trim at an angle so the transition is less stark:

[image]

A slow and steady pull-saw could probably achieve this solution but make sure to protect your flooring from the blade once you get near the floor.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the vertical trim not on the door frames.

Comment: @crip659 Edited to reflect that revelation =)